# jQuery not loading in new IE window

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer

First off, I'd like to preface this question by expressing how unfathomably much I hate IE. Sometimes I wake up in the middle of the night from IE-induced nightmares, causing me to leap out of my bed screaming and sometimes mercilessly beating anyone around me. My neighbors hate it. Just hearing "IE" makes me cringe. But I digress.

Anyway, I have an page on my MVC web app which launches a new page via AJAX (through a different view) and displays a chart. The problem, however, is that when I open the new window, in IE only, the scripts aren't loaded (or at least they aren't loaded in time?) But I get "jQuery is undefined" on the first reference to the jQuery object.

On a reload, however, everything loads just fine. Any idea what might cause scripts not to load in IE? Chrome and FF work fine.

Here's the ajax call that I use for the new window:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: actionURL + qs,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (outputString) {
                    //$("#reportJSON").html(outputString).fadeIn();
                    var contentFromFirstPage = document.getElementById('reportArea').innerHTML;
                    var printContent = outputString;
                    var windowUrl = 'about:blank';
                    var uniqueName = new Date();
                    var windowName = 'Print' + uniqueName.getTime();
                    var printWindow = window.open(windowUrl, windowName, 'scrollbars=1,menubar=1,height=800,width=600,resizable=1');
                    printWindow.document.write(printContent);
                    printWindow.focus();
                    //printWindow.document.close();

                }
            }).error(function (response) {
                alert("something went wrong here with PrintPreview!!!" + response);
            });
```

and here is the action that the ajax calls:

```
public ActionResult PrintPreview(string reportId, string date, string dateFrom, string dateTo)
        {
            Reports reports = new Reports
            {
                ReportId = Convert.ToInt64(reportId),
                Date = Convert.ToDateTime(date),
                DateFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(dateFrom),
                DateTo = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTo),
                AvailableReports = this.FetchAvailableReports()
            };



            reports.AvailableReports = this.FetchAvailableReports();
            reports.SelectedReport = this.FetchReportLayout(reports.ReportId);
            reports.DynamicGridDataSource = this.FetchReportGrid(reports);
            reports.DynamicChartDataSource = this.FetchReportChart(reports);

            return renderViewToString("PrintPreview", reports);
        }
```

Comment: How exactly are the scripts loaded? What does the code for the page loaded into the new window look like?

Comment: like this: `<script src="/RoadMap/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` and I'm not gonna be able to post the source, but there isn't anything unusual about the code. It loads a telerik chart or grid depending on the context

Comment: @Pointy oh and the new window goes through a different view page

Comment: I use to have a similar issue few years ago the solution was I moved the javascript includes at the bottom of the page (the page that opens in new window) . Hope the same works for you

Comment: Magic Ball is in the shop for repairs so we only can guess. Use a tool like Fiddler and watch the http traffic, is the correct files being requested. Are the order of includes correct?

Comment: And all the jQuery calls / functions are in a `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`? Could you try calling a seperate function with a slight timeout using `window.setTimeout(...);`?

Comment: @RemarkLima well yeah, they are, but that wouldn't matter anyway, since the `$` in `$().ready()` is just an alias to the jQuery object, so it`d fail on that call regardless

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt a very valid point! As a fudge, you could always place the whole lot in a vanilla JavaScript function, then just use `window.setTimeout("functionsWithjQuery()",500)`, it's not pretty but could allow you to carry on with more important parts of your project?

Comment: @RemarkLima yeah, but then I'd never know what this issue was :) can't learn anything if you don't spend the time solving problems, right?

Comment: what version of IE? which have you tried?

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt very true, and as a purist I'll always go to try and find the root cause! But sometimes these things need to be put on the TODO list! You've tried referencing jQuery from the Google CDN?

Comment: @r0m4n IE 8. That's the only version of IE i have tried it in. I don't have a later version installed, so I haven't tested it with a later version.

Comment: @RemarkLima yep. Tried every imaginable form of getting jQuery

Comment: Use http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage for multiple versions of IE. Can you post the JavaScript code that opens the new window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, from the discussions I'm going to take a punt at an answer!

Thinking about it, and how it's often with the pain caused by IE, it just a bug / implimentation difference in the raw code, and without actually being able to rewrite the browser behaviour you're in essence out of luck - much like many of the required CSS hacks just for IE.

However, from looking at the code you've posted, I'm assuming the ajax call take the current page, does some stuff with it and returns a print friendly formatted load of HTML? This HTML is then printed into the new window...

Now the only way around this I can think is to go for a slight change to your architecture; The new window will need to open a page, and the ajax call is made on that page to popuate the contents.

However, I would say, IMHO the real use of Ajax calls is that you can remain in the same window, page, and contents without a refresh. As you're opening a new window, I'd have thought just a straight URL with the report ID, date, DateFrom and DateTo in the querystring would work better?

If it's a time issue (the report takes a while to generate), then personally I'd just pass the contents into the new window, and have the new window script inject that into a `div`.

And then look at this as a Cross Browser solution, rather than using a `setTimeout` IE hack ;)